# Overlay image with text, save, and share

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

We are looking into a solution that:

1. takes a user uploaded image
2. allows users to enter some text
3. applies the text as an image overlay over the original image and exports the final image so users can share

We've seen some examples such as https://nisolo.com/pages/inmynisolos, https://www.hillaryclinton.com/trumpyourself/, and http://www.corepoweryoga.com/whyiyoga but we couldn't figure out if they are customized solutions, a paid solution, or just some javascript widget? Anyone have suggestions? We are using Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: And it's far to broad as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good resource that will get this working.

[CarrierWave, Cloudinary and the path to Image Manipulation Enlightenment](http://brewhouse.io/2016/04/12/cloudinary.html)

**Look at Problem 3: Making it dynamic… with Cloudinary in particular**

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful.